# PHP Mail sent without the variables

Tags: php, email, variables

I am setting up a payment page, I am a designer and not a developer. So I have been having some problems. When the payment is made it goes through several stages and a response is generated. In the response.php file that is returned I have an opportunity to inject some code to send an email to the client to inform him that he has received a payment.

The mail is indeed sent to the client but the variables are missing. I receive the text info. Anyone out there that can help would be much appreciated.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$client = $_POST['CUST_NUM'];
$amount = $_POST['AMOUNT'];

$email_from = 'payments@rcehholidaytrust.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "RCEH Website Payment Activity";
$email_body = "You have received a payment from a client $name.\n".
"Account Number:\n $client".
$to = "patrick@patrickmchugh.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

Comment: Not really sure about what you want. But add those variables into $email_body For example: $email_body = "Hello $name Your email address is $email and amount is: $amount"; Hope this helps and this is what you are looking for.

Comment: what r u getting in body?

Comment: Lolcoder  Thanks for getting back - The body text coming to me is  "You have received a payment from a client .
Account Number:
patrick@patrickmchugh.com"

Comment: StudioArena- thanks for getting back, I have the variables in there, but the email is not returning the variables.

Comment: @user2314514 - are you sure that your form is passing the right variables? `CUST_NUM` and `AMOUNT` are both in upper case - are they in upper case in your form? Try adding a `var_dump($_POST)` to the PHP to see what you're passing in.

Comment: They are uppercase, to be honest, I don't write code. Your suggestion is is something I considered. I assume it is common practice to use upper case? But not a necessity?

Comment: Post the HTML of your form.

Answer (score 0):

**i changed my answer based on your description**

so if you are not retrieving the $_POST variables then the problem lies not in the PHP code but in your HTML form page*:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];       
$email = $_POST['email'];
$client = $_POST['CUST_NUM'];
$amount = $_POST['AMOUNT'];
```

can you check if your form fields contain the same names as the list above inside the $_POST.
for example:

$_POST['name'] will get it's values from a textbox/field that has a name='name':

```
<input type="textbox" name="name">
```

$_POST['CUST_NUM'] will get it's values from a textbox/field that has a name='CUST_NUM':

```
<input type="textbox" name="CUST_NUM">
```

**now if you are still having problems getting those variables:**

it might be because you are not passing it in the right url

if your php code your_php_code.php
nd your html is found in the same directory:

```
<form method="POST" action="your_php_code.php">
... your other codes here ...
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried your code, but still getting the same result,  I also went and re-filled out the form. But the same result. You mentioned "how to know? try to substiture the ff and test your code:   " What do you mean by this?

Comment: sorry for the late reply: for example cnange the variable `$name = $_POST['name'];` to `$name = 'my name';` there is a big chance that your script doesn't receive those $_POST variables.

Comment: You are right - I changed it to $name = 'Ronan'; left the other variables unchanged and it sent back "You have received a payment from a client Ronan.
Account Number:"

Comment: post your code for the HTML form where the data is being extracted: it looks like this: `<form>....etc....</form>`.